# Understanding Rust function parameter type declaration

Tags: rust

I was reading the [chapter on higher order functions of Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/fn/hof.html). Where they present the following canonical example:

```
fn is_odd(n: u32) -> bool {
    n % 2 == 1
}

fn main() {
   let upper = 1000;

   println!("imperative style: {}", acc);

   let sum_of_squared_odd_numbers: u32 =
       (0..).map(|n| n * n)                             // All natural numbers squared
            .take_while(|&n_squared| n_squared < upper) // Below upper limit
            .filter(|&n_squared| is_odd(n_squared))     // That are odd
            .fold(0, |acc, n_squared| acc + n_squared); // Sum them
}
```

Simple enough. But I realized that I don't understand the type of parameter `n_squared`. Both `take_while` and `filter` accept a function that takes a parameter by reference. That makes sense to me, you want to borrow instead of consuming the values in the map.

However, if `n_squared` is a reference, why don't I have to dereference it before comparing its value to limit or equally surprising; why can I pass it directly to `is_odd()` without dereferencing?

I.e. why isn't it?

```
   |&n_squared| *n_squared < upper
```

When I try that the compiler gives the following error:

```
error[E0614]: type `{integer}` cannot be dereferenced
  --> src\higherorder.rs:13:34
   |
13 |         .take_while(|&n_squared| *n_squared <= upper)
   |
```

Indicating that `n_squared` is an `i32` and not `&i32`. Looks like some sort pattern matching/destructuring is happening here, but I was unable to find the relevant documentation.

Comment: If you write `|n_squared|`, you'll get the expected error and using `*n_squared` in the body will fix it. See https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/16b9wh/tutorial_question_destructuring_in_stack_closures/

Comment: Since I edited the comment and you might not have seen it: I've added a link to an old Reddit discussion of exactly this issue https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/16b9wh/tutorial_question_destructuring_in_stack_closures/. While Rust has changed a lot, this seems to still be what's going happening.

Comment: The documentation is in https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#function-parameters.`

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Perfect! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [function parameter destructuring](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#function-parameters):

```
|&n_squared| n_squared < upper
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
|n_squared| *n_squared < upper
```

To understand this better, imagine you're passing a tuple of type &(i32, i32) to a lambda:

```
|&(x, y) : &(i32, i32)| x + y
```